# How can i Link the Y Value of a textbox to a Barslider/Trim Path

Tags: layers, effects, adobe-after-effects

Im currently animating a Bar Graph in After Effects.

I linked my Trim Paths on my bars to respective Bar Sliders.
Then I created a Textbox also Referencing the Number on the Bar slider. This all works.

Now I want to add, that my textboxes moves up and down with the bar. Means when the value and the Height of the Bar changes, so should the height of my textbox. How can I link that?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Sorry but video editing and video software is off-topic here. You should ask on Video Production Stack Exchange instead.